# Router Linksys RV042 WAN2 problem

Tags: router, linksys

I've got a brand new Linksys RV042, firmware 1.3.12.6-tm, completely factory configuration, and the WAN2 port doesn't appear to work - it never gets an IP address.

I've got a DSL and Cable connection, either work plugged in to the WAN1 port, neither work plugged in to WAN2. It shows the link light and activity, but never gets an IP address and never tries to send traffic over the link.

I've tried a bunch of things, including switching from failover to load balancing, setting it as the default port, setting a static IP address, changing the WAN2 mac address, but nothing works.

I've seen a few other mentions of this - is the router just a dud or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have it configured for dual WAN? Does the DSL connection use PPOE? If so, have you configured it as such? Have you read and followed the setup guide?

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/csbr/rv042/quick_start/guide/RV042_QIG.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I had all ready find the problem. In the WAN2 configuration you can't change the MAC address. You have to use the default value.